# Locomote player gives this error: Object {code: 731, message: "Socket reported a security error: Error #2048."}

Tags: rtsp, flash

I am using red5pro for rtsp streams and I need flash player to play live streams over rtsp.
Locomote is giving this error

```
Object {code: 731, message: "Socket reported a security error: Error #2048."}
```

I am not very familiar with the socket policy. Can somebody help me out in this?